# Flink GlobFilePathFilter, how to set the specific included file in the included pattern

Tags: filesystems, apache-flink, filefilter

```
 GlobFilePathFilter globFilePathFilter = new GlobFilePathFilter(
            Collections.singletonList("**"),
            Collections.singletonList("**.zip")
    );
```

Not able to set other included patter except the "**".

We want only filter the specific files, like

Collections.singletonList("**AA.txt")

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Flink 1.4 doesn't support this, you have to go the folder level to do this.